# Linewidth in longtabu

Tags: longtable, overleaf, longtabu

I'm trying to understand why my Latex code is wrapping text in column 2 when I apply `\linewidth`. There is plenty of space for the name of the column. I simply want that the headers' names are written out and autofit to the size of the column content.

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\newlength{\asdf} 
\setlength{\asdf}{\textwidth}

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {>{\raggedright}X>{\raggedright}X>{\raggedleft}X>{\raggedleft}X}
\caption{My caption.}\\
\toprule
\textbf{Index} & \textbf{Unique expression} & \textbf{\textit{n}} & \textbf{\%}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize(To be continued)}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\addlinespace
1 & pa & 610 & 29.16\\
2 & tsa & 462 & 22.08\\
3 & ta & 305 & 14.58\\
4 & wa & 90 & 4.30\\
5 & pam & 75 & 3.59\\
6 & gwa & 57 & 2.72\\
7 & ya & 52 & 2.49\\
8 & pum & 43 & 2.06\\
9 & wam & 41 & 1.96\\
10 & sta & 37 & 1.77\\
11 & tsan & 29 & 1.39\\
12 & um & 28 & 1.34\\
13 & gwam & 23 & 1.10\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtabu}
```

[image]

I tried other ways to introduce the long table: `%\begin{longtabu}{@{}rrll@{}}`, however, the table is not page wide although the column is not wrapped-up.

[image]

**[Current workaround]** with
`\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cccc@{}}`

[image]

Comment: Please read https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/blob/main/README.md

Comment: do not use (long)tabu. The package is broken and unmaintained.

Comment: Tray to use `tabularray` package and its `longtblr` table.

Comment: @Zarko _(Tom from Overleaf Support here)_ As [tag:overleaf] has been tagged, I expect @Jo-Achna does this on Overleaf. In that case I just want to mention that `tabularray` is so slow that even very reasonably-sized projects easily time out on Overleaf, and it's really not something we know how to tackle. So I would recommend against using this package, at least until significant improvements to its efficiency are made.

Comment: @yo', in generally `tabularray` is slower than "classic" table package. In my local LaTeX installation compilation time is about 15 second (I5 processor, 4GB RAM), on Overleaf 10 second more (probably to slov internet connection: 4Mb/0.5Mb. However writing tables using it gives shorter and concise code.I hope, that new version of it will speed up compilation  (what seems not be simple to do).

Comment: Thank you for chipping in. I was not aware that this package is not in use anymore. Oddly enough, the ```linewidth``` stopped working as expected once I added the ```Index``` column. Currently, my workaround would be to use ```\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rrll@{}}``` (see description with edits). It's still not what I want, but it's just a compromise for now.

Comment: @yo': You are right, I'm running my document on Overleaf.

Answer (score 1):

With `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\SetTblrStyle{contfoot}{font=\footnotesize\itshape}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {My caption.},
  label = {longtab:1}
                ]{width=0.5\linewidth,
                    colspec = {Q[c, m, si={table-format=2.0}]
                               X[l, m]
                               Q[c, m, si={table-format=3.0}]
                               Q[c, m, si={table-format=2.2}]
                             },
                  row{1}  = {guard, font=\bfseries},
                  rowsep  = 0pt,
                  row{odd[2-X]} = {belowsep=1ex},
                  rowhead = 1
                  } 
    \toprule                   
Index       
    &   Unique expression   
            &   \textit{n}  
                    &   \%  \\
\midrule
 1  & pa    & 610   & 29.16 \\
 2  & tsa   & 462   & 22.08 \\
 3  & ta    & 305   & 14.58 \\
 4  & wa    &  90   &  4.30 \\
 5  & pam   &  75   &  3.59 \\
 6  & gwa   &  57   &  2.72 \\
 7  & ya    &  52   &  2.49 \\
 8  & pum   &  43   &  2.06 \\
 9  & wam   &  41   &  1.96 \\
10  & sta   &  37   &  1.77 \\
11  & tsan  &  29   &  1.39 \\
12 & um & 28 & 1.34\\
13 & gwam & 23 & 1.10\\
 1  & pa    & 610   & 29.16 \\
 2  & tsa   & 462   & 22.08 \\
 3  & ta    & 305   & 14.58 \\
 4  & wa    &  90   &  4.30 \\
 5  & pam   &  75   &  3.59 \\
 6  & gwa   &  57   &  2.72 \\
 7  & ya    &  52   &  2.49 \\
 8  & pum   &  43   &  2.06 \\
 9  & wam   &  41   &  1.96 \\
10  & sta   &  37   &  1.77 \\
11  & tsan  &  29   &  1.39 \\
12 & um & 28 & 1.34\\
13 & gwam & 23 & 1.10\\

 1  & pa    & 610   & 29.16 \\
 2  & tsa   & 462   & 22.08 \\
 3  & ta    & 305   & 14.58 \\
 4  & wa    &  90   &  4.30 \\
 5  & pam   &  75   &  3.59 \\
 6  & gwa   &  57   &  2.72 \\
 7  & ya    &  52   &  2.49 \\
 8  & pum   &  43   &  2.06 \\
 9  & wam   &  41   &  1.96 \\
10  & sta   &  37   &  1.77 \\
11  & tsan  &  29   &  1.39 \\
12 & um & 28 & 1.34\\
13 & gwam & 23 & 1.10\\

 1  & pa    & 610   & 29.16 \\
 2  & tsa   & 462   & 22.08 \\
 3  & ta    & 305   & 14.58 \\
 4  & wa    &  90   &  4.30 \\
 5  & pam   &  75   &  3.59 \\
 6  & gwa   &  57   &  2.72 \\
 7  & ya    &  52   &  2.49 \\
 8  & pum   &  43   &  2.06 \\
 9  & wam   &  41   &  1.96 \\
10  & sta   &  37   &  1.77 \\
11  & tsan  &  29   &  1.39 \\
12 & um & 28 & 1.34\\
13 & gwam & 23 & 1.10\\

 1  & pa    & 610   & 29.16 \\
 2  & tsa   & 462   & 22.08 \\
 3  & ta    & 305   & 14.58 \\
 4  & wa    &  90   &  4.30 \\
 5  & pam   &  75   &  3.59 \\
 6  & gwa   &  57   &  2.72 \\
 7  & ya    &  52   &  2.49 \\
 8  & pum   &  43   &  2.06 \\
 9  & wam   &  41   &  1.96 \\
10  & sta   &  37   &  1.77 \\
11  & tsan  &  29   &  1.39 \\
12 & um & 28 & 1.34\\
13 & gwam & 23 & 1.10\\

    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]